# How to register my service with path on Consul

Tags: wildfly, consul

I have my set of services deployed on a Wildfly instance at

```
http://wildfly:80/service1
http://wildfly:80/service2
```

How do I register these services into consul client?

When I register any service on consul it gives me the address of the Wildfly welcome page.

As, the register service does not have any options for giving a path other than the port.

https://www.consul.io/docs/agent/http/agent.html#agent_service_register

Comment: Consul's service catalog only supports registering IP/hostnames and ports for a given service. It does not support associating HTTP info with a given service registration (see the list of supported [parameter](https://www.consul.io/api-docs/agent/service#parameters-2)s for the `/v1/agent/service/register` endpoint). Consul's service mesh supports [L7 traffic management](https://www.consul.io/docs/connect/l7-traffic), but that introduces additional complexity.

Can you provide more detail on the workflow you're trying to achieve? There may be a different way to solve this problem.

Comment: I'm trying to register applications that are deployed on wildfly server as services on Consul   since those applications are not on "/" path. I have a problem accessing them.